# list of maven repository URL's

Tags: maven, nexus

I'm attempting to migrate from ANT to Maven and keep running into problems contact the remote download sites. They are being blocked by our server, this scans pages for 'undesired words' and then blocks the relevant page, I'm not sure why POM or Jars would have words referencing hardcore porn, but our server certainly seems to think they do! (by the way the server is on ClearOS (in case you are interested)

so far I have been able to get past a number of these by using nexus (not sure I understand why this worked?) but each time I re-run maven on a new test project I get a different set of errors on a different URL!

I then have to email a request to our Network admin to unblock the site, so as I can retrieve the POMs and Jars. To say the least he is getting a bit fed up with the whole thing!

I would contemplate setting up a mirror, but for personal use it seems a bit like overkill maybee I'll get around to having my own 'home server' then maybe I will become a small local mirror.

So what I would like is a list of the principle URLs that I can then give to my network admin and ask him to deblock them all in one hit. However I seem not to be able to find a 'difinitive list' of publicly hosted maven repo URLs.

My current solution is to run the same maven tasks at home (on the same project) and then copy the POMs and jars into the local M2 directory. This works OK but is just a little agravating, especially since I'm not using what I feel are particuarly unusual third party libraries (mostly I'm using stuff from Apache, Eclipse and a few other Open Source projects).

I also found the 'nexus-maven-repository-index' file (under the M2 directory) but it doesn really help very much...its full of strange extended characters and glyphs, so I can't extract any info from it.

I'm really scratching my head here, I am happy to keep using ANT for my individual small projects, but I'm getting to the point where they are all coming together in one horrid goliathan prehistoric nightmare, and they all point to various libraries, and I don't want to release my code onto my colleagues (or publically) with out being able to have a separate list of all the libraries I've used in one location and my principly app in the main source directory.

I am also contemplating IVY but I get the impression I'll just end up with the same issue getting the poms and java libraries.

I am looking for any solution whereby my net admin can allow trafic to Nexus (ie can I set nexus to only work on a specific port and therefore all communication can be filtered to allow outgoing comms on that port to be free - or can I run nexus as a specific user, and then open that user to fully open communications?

Any suggestions will be eagerly received.

Thanks in advance.

David.

ps, if you need any further info please just ask. Oh and sorry for the long post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only really known location is [Maven Central](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) all others have repositories as well, but there is no complete list of that. Furthermore the Eclipse foundation has started to create their own Maven repository but i don't know in which state their repository is and which artifacts are located inside. The other point is you should handle the way to allow Nexus only to access the internet and turn off browsing remote inside Nexus.
On the other hand you will run into the same trouble with all build tools like Ivy, Gradle etc. cause they use the same ideas and infrastructure (Maven repositories).

Comment: There is precisely my problem. I'm permanently getting errors in other locations that nexus is trying to hook into. It is getting rather annoying. I guess I need to hurry up and get my home server up and going so I can then use that as my personal mirror from work, and then I shouldn't have any of these problems

Comment: I found this web page, OK so not a list of actual URLs but mirrors are at least it is partway there. http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Mirrors+Repositories